# Cursor issue in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

Followed this [tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html), faced cursor problem in SimpleCursorAdapter. In tutorial example working as intended. In my code it is showing an error "The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter is undefined". No idea what was undefined. Code look like this:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
    if (inputText == null || inputText.length() == 0) {
        cursor = myDataBase.query(true, GL_TABLE, new String[] { GL_ID,
                GL_FK, GL_LANG, GL_VALUE}, GL_FK
                + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, null, null, null,
                null);

    } else {
        cursor = myDataBase.query(true, GL_TABLE, new String[] { GL_ID,
                GL_FK, GL_LANG, GL_VALUE}, GL_VALUE
                + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, null, null, null,
                null);
    }
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    String[] columns = new String[] { GL_FK, GL_LANG, GL_VALUE};

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvWord, R.id.tvMeaning, R.id.tvKanji};

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listword,
            cursor, columns, to, 0);
```

Comment: Error is here:dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listword,
            **cursor**, columns, to, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the class ?

```
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```

If you did, then be sure to call the constructor with the right kind of parameters. "this" should stand for an activity or a context. if you are in a Runnable or in a clicklistener you will have to call the super MyActivty.this

Comment: Thanks a bunch my friend :) You gave me main hint: changed this->mContext(I dont know what is this, but it is working). Thank U!